# Where to implement a "success" message code in the validator script?

Tags: php, html, forms, jquery, webforms

This php/ajax/jquery thing is new to me, but I do have a much better understanding of HTML/CSS.

I'm developing a site [http://vgdesign.net/thc/] and one of the things left to do is program the form to do exactly what I want. To my knowledge it's functioning fine- except I want it to do just one more thing. When the submit button is pressed, and the code passes validation, I would like for a "Thank You" message to be displayed like below and also without refreshing the page.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkMAI.png]

I found a code that should essentially do just that:

```
$(function() {

$("#send").click(function() {


    var name = $("#name");
    var email = $("#email");
    var comments = $("#comments");


    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&comments=' + comments;


    if(name=='' || email=='' || comments=='')
    {
    $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();

    }

    else
    {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(){
    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();

   }

});

    }

    return false;
    });

});
```

This code was taken from http://www.9lessons.info/2009/04/submit-form-jquery-and-ajax.html
Now I should mention since this doesn't work, this could be disregarded..maybe there's a different way of achieving what I want. I'm just showing where my research has taken me. I have .success defined in my stylesheet and it's at {display:none} but I can't get it to work due to my limited knowledge of the language.

I'm assuming I need to figure out a way to integrate the code above into my validation code so that the message displays right after a validation has succeeded. I used http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/ for the validation tool.

Any help on this would be appreciated. I hope I wasn't too confusing.
Please let me know if I can clarify anything else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ which tells you how to use the jQuery API to POST requests and handle the response. It also has some nice examples.

If you are using jQuery 1.5 you can make it really clear to read:

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.post("example.php", function() {
  alert("success");
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
var name = $("#name");
var email = $("#email");
var comments = $("#comments");
```

to this

```
var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var comments = $("#comments").val();
```

you were saving what I am assuming was a form element, not the value entered into the form element.
you can also use the `$.post()` function instead of the `$.ajax()` which takes a first value of the remote base url, a second value of an object with your `dataString` as key, values and the callback function as the third value.

```
$.post(
  'example.html',
  { 'name' : name, 'email' : email, 'comments' : comments},
  function(data){
    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
  }
);
```

the data variable will hold your response from the ajax call which it seems like you don't need right now.  But for next time ;)